# Sample size calculation for non-normal data

Tags: sample-size, reliability, tolerance-interval

I have a dataset that is not normally distributed - trying to prove 99.7% reliability of it being less than spec (spec=250). We typically would've used tolerance intervals if the data was normal for 95% confidence of 99.7% reliability, but in this case, that doesn't seem appropriate. I've tried to use Minitab's distribution analysis tool and none fit. What can I do besides using the binomial?

[image: data image]

Comment: You need a model, because you won't succeed with the nonparametric (Binomial) approach unless you have more data--around 1200 observations or so.  It won't do to fit a distribution because what matters is the fit in the upper tail, which will be highly uncertain: your model must be based on other data or on theoretical understanding of the data generation process.